# json data not display in ng grid in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, json, angular, ejb

I am working on one project which is based on EJB, AngularJS, restful web services and JPA.

I have created a web service and it will return data from database in JSON format to client.

At client side, I want to display this JSON data in `ng-grid` but the data not getting displayed.

Below is my code:

**JS code**

```
dashboard.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/rest/testentity').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.mydata = data;
        console.log("data response : " + $scope.mydata);
    });
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: $scope.mydata,
        enableRowSelection: false,
        enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        columnDefs: [{
                field: 'id',
                displayName: 'id',
                enableCellEdit: false
            },
            {
                field: 'testname',
                displayName: 'testname',
                enableCellEdit: false
            },
            {
                field: '',
                displayName: 'Save',
                enableCellEdit: false,
                cellTemplate: '<button id="editBtn" type="button"  ng-click="saveItem(row.entity.testname)" >Save</button>'
            }
        ]
    };
});
```

In the console, it will display proper data

**console Output**

```
 data response : [object Object],[object Object]
```

Please suggest what is wrong with my code.

Comment: can you add plunkr

Comment: check this $scope.mydata = data.data; console.log( $scope.mydata);

Comment: @Manikandan data.data is undefined

Comment: $scope.mydata = data; console.log( $scope.mydata); this one what you are getting?

Comment: [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: did you can't see inside object?

Comment: data[0].(getData); add plnkr.

Comment: actual output is this [{"id":1,"testname":"test1"},{"id":2,"testname":"test2"}]

Answer (score 1):

try to

```
$scope.mydata = data.data;
```

object maybe inside object

Answer (score 0):

This maybe the case that, the ng-grid is being initialized before the data is actually available in the scope i.e in `$scope.data`from service. If that maybe the case you have to write the initialization after the service has return successfully. Try these **2 options**.
**1st:** You can write '$scope.gridOptions' initialization inside the `$http` success block.
Example code can be:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/WebApplication2/rest/testentity').
success(function(data) {
    $scope.mydata = data;
    console.log("data response : " + $scope.mydata);
    initializeGridOptions();
});
var initializeGridOptions = function(){
     $scope.gridOptions = {
       data: $scope.mydata,
       .....,
       .....
     };

};
```

**OR**
**2nd:** You can write the initialization inside a `$timeout`

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.gridOptions = {
       data: $scope.mydata,
       .....,
       .....
     };

}, 200);
```

`$timeout` service will wait for some time(200ms) here before exceuting the code, so we can expect service to return the data by then.(You can further increase the time if you want.)

Comment: You will have make a plunkr with your code.
Here use this plukr and update it with you code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/aprCGm8uvY1kzDOr8Avu?p=preview **updated**